# How to add a foreign key column to AspNetUserRoles table Owin Authentication

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I am currently working on a MVC 5 project where I have created a new table (code first) AspNetApplications (column1 ApplicationId, column2 ApplicationName).

I want to extend the AspNetUserRoles table where I want to add ApplicationId as a foreign key column.

Could please anyone tell me how I can achieve this in code first approach?

Answer (score 3):

Above to my question, I have successfully added the ApplicationId as a foreign key column in AspNetUserRoles table as follow

```
public class AspNetUserRoles : IdentityUserRole
{
    [Key]
    public string ApplicationId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ApplicationId")]
    public AspNetApplications AspNetApplications { get; set; }
}
```

Now I can see ApplicationId column in the table but a weird thing happened where it has added a Discriminator column to the AspNetUserRoles table. Can please someone tell me what I have done wrong here. Following is my migration script

```
public partial class AspNetUserRolesApplicationId : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", "ApplicationId", c => c.String(maxLength: 128));
        AddColumn("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", "Discriminator", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128));
        CreateIndex("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", "ApplicationId");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", "ApplicationId", "dbo.AspNetApplications", "ApplicationId");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", "ApplicationId", "dbo.AspNetApplications");
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", new[] { "ApplicationId" });
        DropColumn("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", "Discriminator");
        DropColumn("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", "ApplicationId");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: after adding the above migration, it will break the Authorize and User Roles functionality if Discriminator column is empty or doesn't have the right value. Here I am referring to another post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352732/usermanager-getroles-doesnt-work-after-extending-the-identityuserrole-in-mvc-5/32353062#32353062 which has the answer to that problem.